# How to automate activex control UI

Tags: c#, .net, automation, activex

We are automating application UI with MS "AutomationElement Class". In same application few activex controls are also available and we are currently unable to automate the controls which are available in Activex. Can you please let me know whether there is any way to automate activex controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here link which I came across
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winuiautomation/archive/2010/05/12/custom-ui-automation-providers-in-depth-part-2.aspx